# Set up remote debugging with PHP 7.2 and Xdebug 2.0

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, webserver, xdebug, remote-server

I need to set up Xdebug on my local machine which will connect to the remote development server.
My *launch.json* in VScode looks like this-

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "hostname": "a.b.c.d", //Remote server IP
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

I have added this code in */etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini* file

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.idekey="vsc"
```

I have added the xdebug extension in my browser.
I get this error when I try to click ***Start Debugging***

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available  a.b.c.d:9000 
code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',   
errno: -4090,   
syscall: 'listen',   
address: 'a.b.c.d',   
port: 9000
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Obviously, `a.b.c.d` is not a real IP address, and will never work. That should likely be replaced with the same IP value as `remote_host`?

Comment: It is actually the real  IP address, I have written a.b.c.d for security purpose

Comment: Oh, thanks for that info, seemed off at first, strictly based on the error message, apologies.

Answer (score 1):

It means something else is already listening on port 9000. For example. PHP-FPM. You need to set the port to something else, such as 9003, as that is what Xdebug 3 uses. You then need to use 9003 both for `xdebug.remote_port` and in `"port" : 9003` in the VS Code `launch.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's probably the other way around. Your local machine has the IDE (vscode + php-debug vscode extension) and the remote development server has the web server with PHP and Xdebug PHP extension. The remote server then connects back to the IDE when a web request starts.

The `hostname` in `launch.json` tells the IDE "on what local network interface" to listen for incoming connections. This should not be needed in most cases and should be removed - the IDE can just listen on all local network interfaces.

The `xdebug.remote_host` on the remote development server should contain the IP of your IDE not localhost - unless you are doing some port forwarding magic.

Obviously the remote server must be ablet to TCP connect to your IDE for this to work.

You are probably also missing path mapping as the PHP source files on your local machine will be in different location than on the remote server.